# How to select newly inserted record(s) in MSSQL stored procedure in case of execution of dynamic insert script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to select newly inserted record in my sql server database.

I know that the right solution for me is this:

```
DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (ID INT)

INSERT INTO MyTable(Name, Address, PhoneNo)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @OutputTbl(ID)
VALUES ('Yatrix', '1234 Address Stuff', '1112223333')
```

But my question is about create insert script and execute it in specific stored procedure.

I wrote these two lines at the end of my stored procedure to insert my data to any table I need.

```
SET @sqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tblName + '(' + @param_Collection + ') ' + 'OUTPUT INSERTED.' + @IDENT_Field + ' values('+ @value_Collection +')';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sqlQuery;
```

All variables declared before.

I don't know how to access the identity field to select proper newly inserted record(s).

Comment: That's not a stored procedure, it's a dynamic sql whis is very dangerous & you should avoid it unless there is no way to do the job.

Comment: @Sami I use it inside stored procedure. is it really dangerous?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

A table-valued parameter must be declared with the `READONLY` option. Thus you can't insert into it.

Even if you declare it in the dynamic SQL, you can insert the data into it, but you can't get the data from the table, because the table variable is isolated from the scope of the dynamic SQL.